# Saving shell script optional parameters to an external file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script, which I run with `./abc.sh`. So, if I run this script with `./abc.sh -s` (suppose), how do I save this optional parameter (-s) in an external file for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $* > myarguments
```

Your arguments will be written (overwritten) to the file 'myarguments' in the current directory.

Comment: While this works fine for the concrete case (`-s`), please note that, if the concrete argument contains white space (`.abc.sh "x   y" z`), your approach would not allow to reconstruct these two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to use a temporary array with a declare buildin:

```
# saving positional arguments into an "args" array
args=("$@")
# saving the array
declare -p args > arguments.txt
# loading the array
. arguments.txt
# converting from "args" array to positional arguments if needed
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: I prefer this one to my very simplistic version.